# material textarea don't fit minRows

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my angular 4 project I have a matTextareaAutosize and I want to set min row to 3, but for some reason I see the min row is only 1 row, probably I have some error in my code:

```
<mat-form-field> <textarea matInput
    placeholder="{{ 'note.labels.note' | translate }}"
    matTextareaAutosize matAutosizeMinRows="3" matAutosizeMaxRows = "5"
    name="notes" #note></textarea> </mat-form-field>
```

Ho can I make it works? I am using material 2.0.0.beta11
And I follow [material](https://material.angular.io/components/input/api)

[image]

Comment: your template works as expected, can you check the console if there is any error?

Comment: none error in the console

Comment: here is the demo working as expected: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-beta-11-qty8bv?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: I see...I don't know why this happening

Comment: What Material beta version you are using?

Comment: material 2.0.0.beta11

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with css min-height and width properties :

**CSS**

```
mat-form-field.txtarea {
    min-height: 100px;
    height: initial;
    width: 100%;
}

mat-form-field textarea {
        height: 65px;
   }
```

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field class="txtarea"> 
   <textarea matInput name="notes" #note 
    placeholder="{{ 'note.labels.note' | translate }}">
   </textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```